# How do I change the video output signal to be correct?

Tags: graphics-card, displayport

I have an ancient NVIDIA Quadro 4000 (2Gb) from a HP workstation Z620 plugged into another system (before you're going to ask, yes, everything is compatible, and yes, I had the same results on the original Z620). The problem is; the DisplayPort doesn't output a valid signal for my monitor to pick up. I am still able to use it but it's only usable using DVI-I or DVI-D.

As you can see here, the output signal is VGA while it should be digital:
[EDID settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NmQH.png)
[Part of system topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T2wT.png) (a cable is plugged into displayport1 into my second monitor)

Driver version is 353.62
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
Also, if you need further information, to solve this issue, I'll be glad to provide that info.

Comment: I know it's a longshot, but try to disconnect the computer from power, press the power switch several times and then wait for several minutes ( source: https://lazyadmin.nl/it/fixing-no-signal-when-connecting-your-displayport-in-5-min/ )

Comment: @Netan I've already tried that, and I've even tried reseeding the GPU